# SHOW COLUMNS FROM table for several selected Fields

Tags: php, mysql

How do I Show columns for specific fields .

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM core_banking_mpesa WHERE FIELD= 'id' , FIELD ='LineNo' , FIELD ='Comments'
```

Comment: SELECT COLUMNS FROM core_banking_mpesa WHERE FIELD= 'id' , FIELD ='LineNo' , FIELD ='Comments' LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' FIELD ='LineNo' , FIELD ='Comments' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: Are you trying to to this `SELECT id, LineNo, Comments FROM core_banking_mpesa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that `WHERE column1='val', column2='val'` is not valid syntax.

You could use `IN()` to select the fields:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM core_banking_mpesa
WHERE FIELD IN('id','LineNo','Comments')
```

Or use `OR`:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM core_banking_mpesa
WHERE FIELD='id' OR FIELD='LineNo' OR FIELD='Comments'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just doing a `SELECT` query instead, requesting those three columns:

```
SELECT id, LineNo, Comments
FROM core_banking_mpesa;
```

If you already know what the columns are, it doesn't make much sense why you would want to use `SHOW COLUMNS` on this table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the database world, **COLUMN** and **FIELD** mean the same thing. So you can't "show columns for specific fields".

However if I understand correctly, you are trying to display data from a MySQL table for a specific set of columns/fields. If that is the case, you can try this. Use **`SELECT`** query this way :

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'core_banking_mpesa';
```